# Method return type list<string> or generic method?

Tags: c#, xml, generics

I would like that the method has a specfic return type, but somehow I cannot make it work.

I have an XML structure:

```
<Notifications>
   <Alerts>
      <Max>3<Max/>
      <Med>2<Med/>
      <Min>1<Min/>
   </Alerts>
</Notifications>
```

I would like to get out the values of `Max`, `Med`, `Min`. But the main point is I DO NOT want any foreach loops at all, I only want that the method has a List<string> return type, or even better to make a generic return type.

The point is, I don't have any custom class (and I don't want to have it) that I would fill its properties.

This is what I have some far, but I got an error on the "List()" annonymus method:

```
Here it returns:
List<string> items = GetAlerts();

//method to read:
public List<string> GetAlerts()
{
    return xmlDoc1.Descendants("Notifications").Elements("Alerts").Select(s => new
    {
        MAX = s.Element("Max").Value,
        MED = s.Element("Med").Value,
        MIN = s.Element("Min").Value
     }).ToList(); //error on this line
}
```

### ----------

---

And how would it look that this method about would be a generic return type? This is NOT OK:

```
Here it returns: 
List<object> items = setBLL2.GetAlert<List<object>>();

public T GetAlert<T>() where T:class
{
    return (T)xmlDoc1.Descendants("Notifications").Elements("Alerts").Select(s => new
    //ERROR up here before (T
    {
         MAX = s.Element("Max").Value,
         MED = s.Element("Med").Value,
         MIN = s.Element("Min").Value
     }).ToList();
}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'T'

Comment: `I DO NOT want any foreach loops at all` How about a `while` loop? Maybe a nice `goto` loop? Maybe a classic `for` loop?  Why in the world would anyone say what amounts to "I need to loop through a structure, but I don't want to loop."

Comment: No loop what so  ever. I want that method returns a collection, so I then use the indexes of it, like:    items[0] = ...

Comment: What exactly do you think `Select` does?

Comment: What does the loop have to do with the return type?

Comment: `The point is, I dont have any custom class (and I dont want to have it)` Well, by far your best option is to use a custom class.  If you want to return an anonymous type you'll need to use either `dynamic` or reflection to get the properties out of it.  Neither is all that nice.  You could also use Tuples, but that's also not pretty in your case.  A simple, custom class/struct is by far the best option.

Comment: As @Servy mentions you should use a custom class - your current approach screams maintenance problem

Comment: You are overcomplicating things.. What's wrong with an auxiliary class and a foreach?

Comment: WHY voting negative?? I am trying hard to learn, and you do the contrary... shame on you.

Comment: I KNOW about using classes. I did that plenty of times. But I want to try not using them.

Comment: *"I know how to use a hammer to drive nails, but what I'd really like to do is use a glass bottle. How do you use a glass bottle to drive nails without lacerating my hands?"* The answer of course is use the right tool for the right job. Don't hammer nails with glass bottles. Don't return anonymous types across generic methods. **If it hurts, don't do it.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot transfer anonymous types across method boundaries (in your case, as the generic type of the `List<T>` that is being returned from your method).

You should define a class or struct with `Max`, `Med`, and `Min` as properties, and initialize a list of its instances from your method.

```
public class Alert
{
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string Med { get; set; }
    public string Min { get; set; }
}

public IList<Alert> GetAlerts()
{
    return (xmlDoc1.Descendant("Notifications").Elements("Alerts").Select(s => 
        new Alert
        {
            Max = s.Element("Max").Value,
            Med = s.Element("Med").Value,
            Min = s.Element("Min").Value
        }).ToList();
}
```

**Edit**: As an alternative, you *could* return a list of dictionaries mapping the property names to their values:

```
public IList<Dictionary<string,string>> GetAlerts()
{
    return (xmlDoc1.Descendant("Notifications").Elements("Alerts").Select(s => 
        new Dictionary<string,string>
        {
            { "Max", s.Element("Max").Value },
            { "Med", s.Element("Med").Value },
            { "Min", s.Element("Min").Value }
        }).ToList();
}
```

You could them access your values using code like:

```
string firstMin = alerts[0]["Min"];
```

Comment: I know, I did that already. But I would like to try to do with out them. Just for a try, if it will work - to learn.

Comment: @MitjaBonca So you did it the correct way, but you want to learn, so you're asking how to do it the wrong way?  If you want to compare your method with other possible methods of solving the same problem, or have people code review you, then go to programmers.stackexchange and see what's better.  Don't ask a question that restricts users from providing the best method of solving the problem.

Comment: You can’t (and even if you could, you shouldn’t). Anonymous types are assumed to be highly localized in scope, only used in the method where they are declared. If you absolutely want to use an anonymous type, then you’ll need to declare them within the same method where they will be used.

Comment: @KirkWoll I didn't, but technically it doesn't answer the question as it violates the OPs (questionable) restrictions on answers.

Comment: @Servy, sometimes the right answer isn't the one the OP wants.

Comment: @KirkWoll That's true, and you'll notice I am clearly of that opinion based on my comments throughout the question.  I am merely stating the most likely reason someone else downvoted it.

Comment: @Servy: The answer addresses the OP’s question with its first sentence: “You cannot transfer anonymous types across method boundaries.” What the OP is requesting cannot be done. The remainder of the answer provides an alternative suggestion.

Comment: @Servy, oh I know.  I've been upvoting every comment of yours I can find on this question. ;)

Comment: @Douglas You can always pass anon types around as object, it's just pretty useless.

Comment: @asawyer: I wasn’t aware of that. Still, as you said, it’s useless since the properties cannot ever be read externally (except through reflection).

Comment: As I said in my first comment to the question itself, you can either use `dynamic` or reflection to pass an anon type around and access it's members, it's just more work and just generally less preferable to making a new named type.  It's not that you *can't*, it's just that it's *less desirable*.

Comment: @Douglas Actually there is a way to read the values without `dynamic` or reflection. Let me find a link....

Comment: @Douglas [Cast by exampler, or, Evil Cast](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx)

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I’m reading the rest of the comments now; I concede that it is technically possible. Notwithstanding, you lose compile-type checking, which is one of the fundamental pillars of C# and all strongly-typed languages. You would probably be better off returning an `IList<Tuple<T,T,T>>` (as implied in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937339/method-return-type-liststring-or-generic-method#comment14270383_10937339)), since you’d lose only the property names.

Comment: @asawyer: Good point. I remember reading that .NET compiles anonymous types having identical parameters into the same class, but didn’t assume it could be exploited this way.

Comment: @Douglas It's per assembly, and pretty evil. Neat though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
void Main()
{
   List<string> alerts =

   XDocument.Parse(Data)
            .Descendants("Alerts")
            .Elements()
            .Select (nd => nd.Value)
            .ToList();

   alerts.ForEach(al => Console.WriteLine ( al ) );     // 3 2 1 on seperate lines

}

// Define other methods and classes here
const string Data = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Notifications>
   <Alerts>
      <Max>3</Max>
      <Med>2</Med>
      <Min>1</Min>
   </Alerts>
</Notifications>";
```

Comment: Note that this will have flaws if the input data is not in the expected order, if there are additional elements, or if there are missing elements.

Comment: @Servy fair enough; but since the OP wanted a list of strings and no indication of serverity order does not appear to be required. This example was meant to show how to get a list of strings out of the Alerts level to maybe show the OP how to do it in his code.

Comment: If you've read my comments elsewhere in this question you've seen that I feel the OPs requirements are overly restrictive and exclude much better solutions to this problem.  My comment was directed not at you, but readers of your answer, to indicate some of the problems you were forced to expose in your answer because of the restrictions in the question itself.  While this solution can work, and it doesn't violate any of the OPs restrictions, my point is that it still has it's flaws and shouldn't be emulated from passerbys seeing this from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get MAX, MED, and MIN returned in separate entries in a List within the LINQ query.  What you can do though, is have your LINQ query put MIN, MED, and MAX into a List  object, and then return the first row.

```
public IList<Alert> GetAlerts() 
{ 
    var xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Parse(XML, LoadOptions.None);
    var entries = xmlDoc1.Descendants("Notifications").Elements("Alerts").Select(s => new
        List<string> {
            s.Element("Max").Value,
            s.Element("Med").Value,
            s.Element("Min").Value
        }).ToList();
    // Make sure we don't get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    if (entries.Count > 0)
    {
        return entries[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

P.S. - Your end tags for MIN, MAX, and MED are formatted incorrectly, the '/' should be before the name, not after.